# Problema ao tentar obter a temperatura da CPU utilizando WMIC

Tags: windows, batch, wmi

Estou criando um programa para `Windows` e preciso obter a temperatura do CPU do usuário. Para essa tarefa estou utilizando o `wmic` com o seguinte código em `batch`:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in (
    'wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value'
) do (
    set /a degrees_celsius=%%a / 10 - 273
)

echo %degrees_celsius% GRAUS
pause
```

O problema é que a temperatura apresentada é sempre `64 GRAUS` e o retorno original do `wmic` é a temperatura em Kelvin de `3372`. Eu fiz vários testes para confirmar se essa temperatura estava correta ou não. Desliguei o computador e esperei um tempo para a CPU esfriar, abri programas de medição de temperatura, e o resultado desse programa em `batch` era sempre o mesmo.

Estou fazendo algo de errado, é algum problema no `wmic` ou a falta de algum recurso no meu computador ?

Comment: Só fortalecendo, aqui também o valor não está alterando, Windows 10. Coloquei o CPU pra teste de stress e o valor não muda.

Comment: Porque não puxa direto da API do Windows escrevendo algum aplicativo? Tenho um aplicativo de leitura de temperatura via API e funciona de boa em todas as versões acima do Windows 7.

Comment: O programa que estou criando é em Python. Eu procurei na documentação da API do Windows "pywin32" mas não tem nada lá relacionado à temperatura. Antes que alguém fale, as bibliotecas que possuem funções de medição de temperatura para Python não funcionam no meu computador (testei todas as bibliotecas que achei na internet).

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazer no Windows 8.1, mais quando fui tentar o mesmo batch no Windows 10 não deu certo (eu tentei rodar ele no Windows 10 por conexão remota porque não tenho acesso a um Windows real no momento.

```
@echo off
Title Mostrando a temperatura da CPU
:start
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation get temperature"') do set /a Temperatura_Kelvin=%%a& goto Calculos

:Calculos
set /a Temperatura_Celcius=(%Temperatura_Kelvin%*100)-27315
set /a inteiros=%Temperatura_Celcius:~0,-2%
set /a quebrados=%Temperatura_Celcius:~-2%
set Temperatura_Celcius=%inteiros%,%quebrados%
set /a Temperatura_Fahrenheit=(%Temperatura_Kelvin% * 100 - 27315) * 9 
set /a Sobra_Fahrenheit=%Temperatura_Fahrenheit% %% 5
set /a Temperatura_Fahrenheit=%Temperatura_Fahrenheit% / 5
set /a inteiros=%Temperatura_Fahrenheit:~0,-2% + 32
set /a quebrados=%Temperatura_Fahrenheit:~-2% + %Sobra_Fahrenheit%
set Temperatura_Fahrenheit=%inteiros%,%quebrados%
cls
echo.
echo.
echo   Temperatura da CPU: %Temperatura_Celcius%ø Celcius ^| %Temperatura_Kelvin% Kelvin ^| %Temperatura_Fahrenheit%ø Fahrenheit
echo.
timeout /t 1 > Nul
goto :start
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por alguma razão sempre que você usa a formula para converter Kelvin para Celcius (Kelvin - 273,15 = Celcius) sempre fica um resto de 85 ou 15....

Comment: Tentei esse código e dessa vez pelo menos ele mostrou algo diferente, porém ainda não é o correto. A saída está sendo esta: "Temperatura da CPU: -1,-2° Celcius |  Kelvin | 32,64° Fahrenheit".

Comment: E qual Windows você usa porque no meu Windows 10 aconteceu algo parecido com isso também.

Comment: Eu uso Windows 7